# Stop loss exit does not leave the strategy completely

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

problem with partial stop loss.

I am trying to create a strategy in which I will have three take profits and one stop loss.
stop loss should completely exit the strategy, but it exits partially.

```
if(signals_view == "Buy/Sell"))
   strategy.entry("LongBuy", strategy.long)
 
if(signals_view == "All")
    strategy.entry("ShortSell", strategy.short)

if( ta.cross( close, current_top_box ) and strategy.position_size<0) 
    strategy.exit("Exit short SL","ShortSell", stop = current_top_box, qty_percent = 100)     
   
if(ta.cross( close,  current_bottom_box)  and strategy.position_size>0)
    strategy.exit("Exit long SL","LongBuy", stop = current_bottom_box, qty_percent = 100)  

if(selectedCheackBoxTP1)
    strategy.exit ("Exit long TP1 " , "LongBuy",  limit=entryPrice * (1 + tp1_percent),  qty_percent=25)
    strategy.exit ("Exit short TP1", "ShortSell", limit=entryPrice * (1 - tp1_percent),  qty_percent=25)                  
if(selectedCheackBoxTP2)  
    strategy.exit ("Exit long TP2", "LongBuy", limit=entryPrice * (1 + tp2_percent),  qty_percent=25)
    strategy.exit ("Exit short TP2", "ShortSell", limit=entryPrice * (1 - tp2_percent),  qty_percent=25)
if( selectedCheackBoxTP3)  
    strategy.exit ("Exit long TP3", "LongBuy", limit=entryPrice * (1 + tp3_percent),  qty_percent=50)
    strategy.exit ("Exit short TP3", "ShortSell", limit=entryPrice * (1 - tp3_percent),  qty_percent=50)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3xVq.jpg)

I need the stop loss to completely leave the strategy and after it there is no take profit

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing your exit orders conditionally, you need to have on global stop loss price and modify its value conditionally.

```
top_cross = ta.cross(close, current_top_box)
bot_cross = ta.cross(close,  current_bottom_box)

var float stop_loss_price = na
stop_loss_price = top_cross ? current_top_box : bot_cross ? current_bottom_box : stop_loss_price  // Update or keep its old value based on your conditions
```

After that you should use this SL in ALL your exit orders.

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work even without the condition at all. It's just that if there is an exit to qty_percent=100 and after it an exit to qty_percent=25, then in fact the first exit will be at 75 and the second at 25. As shown in the picture